# Yii2 replace spaces with dash when using sluggable behaviour

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

How can I replace spaces with a dash when using sluggable behaviour? As it currently replaces spaces with a plus or percentage symbol.

My Model

```
 public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        TimestampBehavior::className(),
        [
            'class' => SluggableBehavior::className(),
            'attribute' => 'title',

        ],
    ];
}
```

My URL manager config

```
       'urlManager' => [
        'class' => 'yii\web\UrlManager',
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'rules' => [
            // your rules go here
            'article/<id:\d+>/<slug>' => 'article/view',
        ],
    ],
```

Answer (score 0):

This is actually done automatically however I have the following URL setup

.htaccess I have added the below line of code to remove trailing slash from all URLs to prevent possible duplicate content.

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^(.+)/$ $1
```

I also apply the following rules to my model/AR's note the 0-9 this means that if you create an article called test and another one called test the second test will be able to be accessed via test-2.

```
'article/<id:\d+>/<slug:[-a-zA-Z 0-9]+>' => 'article/view',
```